# Proof by induction that $d^nf(x,y,z)=(adx+bdy+cdz)^n\cdot e^{ax+by+cz}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

We have $f:\mathbb{R^3}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},f(x,y,z)=e^{ax+by+cz}$ and we need to proof by induction that $d^nf(x,y,z)=(adx+bdy+cdz)^n\cdot e^{ax+by+cz}$, where $d^nf(x,y,z)$ is n order differential of $f$, $\forall n\in\mathbb{N^*}$

---

Here is all my steps:

- I noted with $\Gamma_{(n)}: d^nf(x,y,z)=(adx+bdy+cdz)^n\cdot e^{ax+by+cz}$.

Verification step: $$n=1\Rightarrow df(x,y,z)=\left[\frac{\partial dx}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial dy}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial dz}{\partial z}\right]\cdot f(x,y,z)=(adx+bdy+cdz)\cdot e^{ax+by+cz}$$

Demonstration step: We suppose that $\Gamma_{(k)}$ is true and we need to proof that it involve $\Gamma_{(k+1)}$ also true. Hence we need to prove that $\Gamma_{(k+1)}: d^{k+1}f(x,y,z)=(adx+bdy+cdz)^{k+1}\cdot e^{ax+by+cz},\forall x\in\mathbb{N^*}$

> How can I prove it?

Comment: Is there an analgous formula for 2 or 1 variables? Can it be obtained by just setting z or z and y equal to a constant such as 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you showed it for n=1. Now suppose the for n=k the equality holds so:

\begin{equation}
d^kf(x,y,z)=(adx+bdy+cdz)^k\cdot e^{ax+by+cz}
\end{equation}

so for n=k+1 all we need to do is find the differential of the function \begin{equation}
(adx+bdy+cdz)^k\cdot e^{ax+by+cz}
\end{equation}

or calculate

\begin{equation}
d\left \{ (adx+bdy+cdz)^k\cdot e^{ax+by+cz} \right \} = \\
= (adx+bdy+cdz)^{k} \cdot (adx+bdy+cdz) \cdot e^{ax+by+cz} = \\
= (adx+bdy+cdz)^{k+1}\cdot e^{ax+by+cz},
\end{equation}

which concludes the induction proof.

Comment: How did you arrive at $(adx+bdy+cdz)^n\cdot (adx+bdy+cdz)\cdot e^{ax+by+cz}$ ?

Comment: by the commutative property of total differential $d\left \{ (adx+bdy+cdz)^n\cdot e^{ax+by+cz} \right \} = (adx+bdy+cdz)^{n} \cdot d \left \{ e^{ax+by+cz} \right \}$

Comment: What you mean by "find the differential of the function ..." ? the differential of the function isn't $(adx+bdy+cdz)\cdot e^{ax+by+cz}$ ?

Comment: It means that to go from k to k+1 we need to differentiate one more time

Comment: And if we differentiate one more time we consider $(adx+bdy+cdz)^k$ constant?

Comment: A,b,c depend on x?? If that is the case then we will have to take another approach.

Comment: I don't understand why did you put "or calculate" because I think is same if we calculate differentiate one more time with $d\left\{(adx+bdy+cdz)^k\cdot e^{ax+by+cz}\right\}$